# How can I know why one of my vxWorks task is pended?

Tags: vxworks

In vxWorks, I can issue the "i" command in the shell, and I get the list of tasks in my system along with some information like the following example:

```
  NAME         ENTRY       TID    PRI   STATUS      PC       SP     ERRNO  DELAY
----------  ------------ -------- --- ---------- -------- -------- ------- -----
tJobTask    1005a6e0     103bae00   0 PEND       100e5860 105fffa8       0     0
tExcTask    10059960     10197cbc   0 PEND       100e5860 101a0ef4       0     0
tLogTask    logTask      103bed78   0 PEND       100e37cd 1063ff24       0     0
tNbioLog    1005b390     103bf210   0 PEND       100e5860 1067ff54       0     0
```

For the tasks that are pended, I would like to know what they are pended on.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "w" command will do exactly what you want:

```
  NAME       ENTRY       TID       STATUS   DELAY  OBJ_TYPE    OBJ_ID   OBJ_NAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----- ---------- ---------- --------
tJobTask   0x1005a6e0 0x103bae00 PEND           0 SEM_B      0x10184088 N/A     
tExcTask   0x10059960 0x10197cbc PEND           0 SEM_B      0x10183ff8 N/A     
tLogTask   logTask    0x103bed78 PEND           0 MSG_Q(R)   0x103be358 N/A     
tNbioLog   0x1005b390 0x103bf210 PEND           0 SEM_B      0x103bf198 N/A
```